# All profile tags display zero when score and number of questions asked are higher than zero

Tags: support, tags

I am talking about the number to the left of the tags listed. I don't know if it's a bug or just something but I'm not understand.

Java tag says I have a score of 8, but displays a 0

[image]

Comment: Questions don't count toward tags scores. Only answers count.

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes sense. My assumption was that it was an aggregate of answers/questions regarding that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number to the left of the tags listed is NET SCORE you get after answer to that particular tag.

All of your answers in that tag are bind together and the scores of these answers are added up.

The net total score for particular tag is the total number of UPVOTES on those answers, minus the total number of DOWNVOTES on the same tag.

This net score is updated each day once around 03:00 UTC.